# how to watch the value change in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a string variable e.g. `createId:string` in Angular component.ts
How to add a breakpoint when this variable change value?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a breakpoint in a setter:

```
   public set createdId(val:string){
      debugger;
      this._createdId=val;
   }
   public get createdId(){
      return this._createdId;
   }
```